# Is it RESTful to use HATEOAS for commands in RPC style

Tags: rest, api, web-services, interface, architecture

In REST resources are identified by their URI and allowed operations are limited to HTTP verbs available. RESTfull API is an uniform interface providing basic CRUD operations for resources over HTTP.

Finally, REST architecture states resources should contain hyperlinks for the client to further traverse the API. This is called HATEOAS (Hypertext as the Engine of Application State). Hyperlinks decouples client code from the interface implementation details.

Is it RESTful to use HATEOAS links to pass imperative commands targeting the resource in RPC style? I think this won't break the uniform interface as all the information is provided in the link. Consider the following example, where action doesn't fit in HTTP verb.

`GET /foo/1`

`{ 
   id: 1,
   foo: "foo",
   links: {
     self: "/foo/1",
     doAction: "/foo/1/do-action" 
   }
}`

`POST /foo/1/do-action`

Or should I just use the request parameters to pass the command information to resource endpoint, or model the command as resource of it's own?

Comment: *RESTfull API is an uniform interface providing basic CRUD operations* Just a note. REST API provides uniform interface. That's it. There is no need to limit the uniform interface to just CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it RESTful to use HATEOAS links to pass imperative commands targeting the resource in RPC style?

REST is an architectural style; if you want to understand how it works, you should look for analogs in applications created using that style.  For REST, the best known of these applications is the World Wide Web.

So the answer to your question comes about from considering how closely your situation maps to achieving useful work on the web; which is to say by navigating through hyperlinks until we find the right form, filling in the data, and then submitting it.

```
{ 
    id: 1,
    foo: "foo",
    links: {
        self: "/foo/1",
        doAction: "/foo/1/do-action" 
    }
}
```

So, from the perspective of REST, the question becomes "how do general-purpose components know what to do with `doAction`?"

On the web, we have a general purpose standard for forms, so the hypermedia representation of the form carries with it the information the client needs to create the correct payload for the request.

In [AtomPub](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023), the standard defines the semantics for the link relations in the various documents, so any general purpose atom client will know how to interpret the data enclosed in the responses.

(In a sense, the definitions of the link relations in Atom are a lot like the definitions of A and FORM in HTML; they are of general utility).

So in your context, the hint "doAction" should be informing the client of something interesting that can be done (POST a cat video here).  The *target uri* shouldn't matter to the client; it should just be sending the request where it is told.

The spelling of the target-uri here doesn't matter at all; but an interesting case to consider is that happens when the target-uri is the same as one you use somewhere else, for example:

```
{ 
    id: 1,
    foo: "foo",
    links: {
        self: "/foo/1",
        doAction: "/foo/1" 
    }
}
```

HTTP has simple [cache-invalidation semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) built into the standard; in effect, your target for `doAction` tells the client which cached representation will be invalidated when the action is successful.